# A request with the GraphServiceclient for notebooks, the query option "select" needs "name" instead "displayname"

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-onenote

With the query option "select" the properties in the requested notenooks can be reduced. If i try this in the Graph explorer, the select statement looks like "$select=id,displayname,createddatetime"
The same procedure with the GraphSeviceClient (UWP, c#) looks like:

```
RequestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("select", "id"));
        RequestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("select", "name"));
        RequestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("select", "links"));
        RequestOptions.Add(new QueryOption("select", "createdTime"));
```

My question is, why are the values in the query options not the same?
name instead displayname
createdTime instead createddatetime

Best regards an thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A request with the GraphServiceclient for notebooks, the query option “select” needs “name” instead “displayname”

Great question, I checked the related document, I think it's by design. The `createdTime` `name` query word are just parameter, and it will matched with  [`displayName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/notebook?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) and [`createdDateTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/notebook?view=graph-rest-1.0) in method internal. For doing this could prevent confusion. For using `QueryOption` we could check this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onenote-get-content) to get the correct query word.

Comment: Thanks for evaluating. The name of the properties, they are used in the query options in the Graph SDK are derived obviously from older Api's where you get the OneNote DOM hierarchy in a Xml format. I remembered this, when I was coding VB in MS Access with the OneNote API...